# how to use TextMagic service with saved phone number in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use TextMagic service for send sms messages to saved phone in database, i tried difference of methods but not working.

```
$y = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE account_num = '$a' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($y) > 0) {
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($y);
    $a1 = $row1['phone_num'];

    $api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
        "username" => "***", 
        "password" => "***"
    ));
    $phone = array('$a1');
    $text = "hello ";
    $results = $api->send($text, $phone, true);
}
```

how can i hold this problem?

Comment: What you mean by not working? Did you test with the number they provide for testing with sucess? Are you sure `$phone` has the number?

Comment: @Berriel yes, i tested  by inserted phone number inside code and it successful, but if the phone number get it from database it  not work. i sure $phone has the number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but: (suppose `$a1 = 999`)

```
$phone = array('$a1'); // array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "$a1" }
```

is different than

```
$phone = array("$a1"); // array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "999" }
```

and different than

```
$phone = array($a1); // array(1) { [0]=> int(999) }
```

Based on [this](http://api.textmagic.com/https-api/sms-api-php-wrapper), looks like the 3rd is the correct option.